# How to mount a vue js child component only when the parent is fully mounted - I'am using $refs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, inertiajs

I am using **Laravel 8 and InertiaJS (Vue js)**

I am using the **html2pdf.js** to generate PDF. So I create a component for that : **ExportPdf.vue**

So here is the  code of the component **ExportPdf.vue** :

```
<template>
  <div>
      <button class="px-6 py-3 rounded bg-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-900 text-white text-sm font-bold whitespace-no-wrap" 
        @click="exportToPDF">Expot to PDF
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js'

export default {
props:{
    area: HTMLDivElement,
    name : String,
    orientation : {
      type: String,
      default(){
        return 'landscape'
      }
    }
},
methods:{
     exportToPDF () {
          html2pdf(this.area, {
            margin: [1.5, 1],
            filename: this.name + '.pdf',
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas: {scale: 2},
            jsPDF: { unit: 'cm', format: 'a4', orientation: this.orientation ,  floatPrecision: 16 }
        })
    }
}
}
</script>
```

And then I'm using this component inside any component which I want to extract the content into PDF file like this :

```
<export-pdf  name="file name" :area="$refs.content" />
```

AND I reference to Div I want to extract using **ref** like :

```
<div ref="content">
 <!-- Content to Extrat into PDF -->
</div>
```

The first time It WORKS but when I change a component (I go to another vue), It doesn't work, So I must refresh the page.

I console log the prop (**this.area** which receive the **$refs.content** from the parent) inside the ExportPdr component => it's undefined.
I think that is because this component is mounted before the $refs.content is initialised in the parent (If I can say that)

I found a solution but In my opinion It is not perfect. Because I need to add **v-if** to ExportPdf component in Each Parent Component and make the boolean to true in the mounted method of the parent. This fixed the problem and the prop is not Undefined anymore. That is all to make it works without refreshing the page every time. BUT it's tedious to add these lines every time to each parent  component.

like this :
**Parent template :**

```
<export-pdf v-if="isMounted" name="Liste des consommables des équipements" :area="$refs.content" />
```

```
data(){
    return {
      isMounted : false,
    }
 }, 
mounted(){
        this.isMounted = true
}
```

So Any suggestoin to make it better ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use the watch and listen to a var to mount the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

- The child component is mounted before parent.
- [$refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html#template-refs) is not reactivity,you should avoid accessing $refs from within templates or computed properties.

**Solution 1:**

```
    <div ref="content">
     <!-- Content to Extrat into PDF -->
    </div>
    <export-pdf  name="Liste des consommables des équipements" :area="refElement" />
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
          refElement: {},
        }
     }, 
    mounted(){
        this.refElement = this.$refs.content
    }
}
</script>
```

**Solution 2:**

parent:

```
 <div ref="content">
 <!-- Content to Extrat into PDF -->
 </div>
 <export-pdf  name="Liste des consommables des équipements" areaRefName="content" />
```

children:

```
props:{
    areaRefName: String,
    name : String,
    orientation : {
      type: String,
      default(){
        return 'landscape'
      }
    }
},
methods:{
     exportToPDF () {
          let element = this.$parent.$refs[this.areaRefName]
          html2pdf(element , {
            margin: [1.5, 1],
            filename: this.name + '.pdf',
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas: {scale: 2},
            jsPDF: { unit: 'cm', format: 'a4', orientation: this.orientation ,  floatPrecision: 16 }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the second Solution and It works fine, just a small detail to add in the child component method "this.area" instead of area only 
          html2pdf(this.$parent.$refs[this.area], { ......}

Maybe someone try the first solution and confirm it. Thanks